# Using Sinch REST Api in C#

Tags: c#, rest, hmac, sinch

I am trying to use Sinch REST api in c# for sms verification and I am having trouble encoding the strings required for Authorization. I am using APPLICATION SIGNED REQUEST for Auth and I would like to know what c# functions to use to created the content-Md5 and stringtoSign. 
For content MD-5 here is the code snippet I have

```
var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(smsRequest);

var hs = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();

var db = hs.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));

var stringToSign = Convert.ToBase64String(db);

 public class SmsRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("identity")]
    public Identity Identity;

    [JsonProperty("method")]
    public string Method;

    [JsonProperty("metadata")]
    public Metadata Metadata;
}

public class Metadata
{
    [JsonProperty("os")]
    public string Os;

    [JsonProperty("platform")]
    public string Platform;

}

public class Identity
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type;

    [JsonProperty("endpoint")]
    public string Endpoint;
}
```

Now for creating the stringtoSign is something I use the following code

```
var stringToSign = "POST" + Environment.NewLine + "jANzQ+rgAHyf1MWQFSwvYw==" + Environment.NewLine +
                  "application/json" + Environment.NewLine + "x-timestamp:2014-06-04T13:41:58Z" +
                  Environment.NewLine + "/v1/sms/+46700000000";//used for signing

var secret = "JViE5vDor0Sw3WllZka15Q=="; // this needs to be signed
var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(stringToSign);

var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte);

byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);
byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);

var res = Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
```

I am using the values in the example here https://www.sinch.com/using-rest/ and I expect the result to be "qDXMwzfaxCRS849c/2R0hg0nphgdHciTo7OdM6MsdnM=" while using my method I am getting "2/8KqdiC2708EC84vTinPchiATRJiZU4Mgfpykb4F40=".

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: i think you are using stringtosign as the key and secret as the thing to be signed. they need to be the other way round

Comment: interchanged the variables and now I get "zNtnvbGn1B0esBeJHAgda87uNEI42UFm9bsAMnub9+U=" which is also not matching the original value.

Comment: Sinch team, please help as this is a potential blocker for my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use our awesome nuget https://github.com/sinch/nuget-serversdk if you dont want to install the nuget you can check the source and take the pieces you want. its opensource and you

Comment: Which VS version is required to build this project? i cannot build it with vs 2012 or above.

Comment: Sdk works perfect but I want to be sure about the licensing terms if I want to use it for commercial purpose.Please advise.

Comment: hey, its pay as you go.

Comment: I can understand that I would be paying for sms/flash calls for each such  operation but my concern was using this nuget package in product code. Does it incur any liability in terms of licensing? What are the license terms for the sdk and can it be used as is?

Comment: its MIT so its no problems at all